# How to add a Tag (which is in the form of a string) to a soup in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a Tag which is available to me as a string only.
Example: tag_str = 'hello'

When I do the following:

```
template_logo_h1_tag.insert(0, tag_str)
```

Where 
template_logo_h1_tag is a h1 tag

the resulting template_logo_h1_tag is

```
<h1 id="logo">&lt;a&gt;hello&lt;/a&gt;</h1>
```

I want to avoid this HTML escaping
and the resulting tag to be

```
<h1 id="logo"><a>hello</a></h1>
```

Is there anything I am missing?
I tried BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES but this to unescape already "html-escaped" strings.
It would be great if you could help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a dirty hack:

template_logo_h1_tag.insert(0, BeautifulSoup('hello').a)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Beautiful Soup's .append method: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append

Coupled with the factory method for creating a new tag: soup.new_tag()

Updating with code:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup('<h1 id="logo"></h1>')
template_logo_h1_tag=soup.h1
newtag=soup.new_tag("a")
newtag.append("hello")
template_logo_h1_tag.append(newtag)
```

Then

```
print soup.prettify
```

yields

```
<h1 id="logo">
 <a>
  hello
 </a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks Anov,
But to use soup.new_tag method, I need to know what type of tag it is and what the attributes are.

I will have access to only the string.
Hence, I have tried this workaround and it is working for me:
newtag.insert(0, BeautifulSoup(given_string))